# How to add default createdAt and updateAt as Today to old mongo data?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some old data, which was imported from a CSV file.
Now I want to add a new default date for createdAt and UpdateAt.

Looking for mongo queries to update my docs for adding createdAt and updatedAt field. (now there is no field as createdAt & updatedAt)

Comment: Setting defaults won't affect data that is already there...

Comment: actually, I mean my old data don't have any field createdAt and UpdatedAt , need to add that. @D.SM

Comment: Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: I just updated my question. hope it will help @D.SM

Comment: Use $set to bulk set a field.